# MCP2210 spi_exchange 2 byte values

Tags: python, microcontroller

I'm using https://github.com/jeremyherbert/mcp2210-python, from what I understand the MCP2210 accepts values up to 59 bits.
In a C# code, I usually send 2-byte values.

From the library, the following code allows sending 1 byte (code sample).

```
rx_data = self.dev.spi_exchange(bytes(255), cs_pin_number = self._channel)
```

What would be the best option to send two-byte values?

I tried the following but the results are unexpected, is this correct?

```
value = [0xff, 0xff] 
rx_data = self.dev.spi_exchange(bytes(value), cs_pin_number = self._channel)
```

Sorry for the noob question, this is my first python experience

Comment: Just on the surface I would say you need looping as `rx_data = [self.dev.spi_exchange(bytes(val), cs_pin_number = self._channel) for val in [0xff, 0xff]]`. This is a list comprehension if you're not familiar with it. In this case `rx_data` should be a list of two response codes.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, the links might die any time. They are links to specific positions of the code in the library mentioned by the OP.

(Without specific underlying knowledge of the library and the USB to SPI Converter MCP2210, and also considering your `self.dev` is a correctly generated instance of [Mcp2210](https://github.com/jeremyherbert/mcp2210-python/blob/75e3c357eae1ed212606a85f4632fd49b6586371/mcp2210/mcp2210.py#L355)).

If you have two bytes you want to send and for which you want to register some communication (as per the def of `spi_exchange` [here](https://github.com/jeremyherbert/mcp2210-python/blob/75e3c357eae1ed212606a85f4632fd49b6586371/mcp2210/mcp2210.py#L663)) you just need to loop (assuming also the hardware is working properly/correctly connected).

```
response = []
for b in [0xff, 0xff]:
    response.append(self.dev.spi_exchange(b, cs_pin_number=self._channel)
```

`response` must then contain two bytes.

Comment: Thank you.. In my case the board is not sending feedback, so the response is not necessary. However, I figured out how to do it. I need to do some conversions to the value I'm sending but my OP syntax was correct, I can send the array all at once by converting with bytes. If I could I would delete the question.